# How color swatches work?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, color-swatches

Can anyone explain to me how color swatches work when changing images? And where it is done?
I want to know where in code it change images.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses **attributes** as swatches. That means that "color" is just the label you have for your swatch, but it could really be anything.

The basic idea is to enable this option under `System > Configuration > Catalog > Configurable Swatches`.

The next step is to create the configurable product using the attribute set you want. Then, under **Images** tab, you add new images with the same label used in the **attributes** page.

Here is a good tutorial with images and more details: https://sherodesigns.com/tutorial-configurable-swatches-in-magento/

About the code, you can find it under `app\code\core\Mage\ConfigurableSwatches\Block\Catalog\Layer\State\Swatch.php` but it is not recommended to change anything there.

Comment: Well that all depends. Does your theme have swatches already attributed to products? If not you would have to create an attribute for this manually. You can also look for an extension that will do this for you.